# MongoDB schema for MEAN stack

Tags: mongodb

I have a set of Data that would look like this

```
title:string
type: string
```

Now depending on the type, (for example `"TV Show"`) I would need another field to display `"Seasons"` and show the number of seasons.

Now if it is a `"movie"` I would need a different array (for `Franchise`) and show the title of each one in the series.

Would I need 2 documents or would a single document be sufficient?  If so, how?

Comment: I am curious for when i would need to post out to the database with angular.

Comment: Try to avoid using personal introductions and other chatty text.  I've removed that text and updated your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific convention on how you would structure this data, it depends mostly on the data itself and how you will be accessing it. Here are a couple options:

## Option 1

You could have 1 document that has title, type, and all of the specific fields for both TV Shows and Movies. When posting to the database, you only include the fields which are applicable to that type.

For Example:

For a movie, you would just post title, type, and franchise.

For a TV show, you would just post title, type and season.

With option 1, you can query both TV shows and Movies with 1 query, but more specific queries are now performed on a potentially larger data pool.

## Option 2

Have 1 document for TV shows and 1 document for Movies, taking the type field out of the equation completely.

Option 2 requires two queries in order to get both TV Shows and Movies, but now you can more clearly query just TV Shows or just Movies.